# How can I recover the Ethereum wallet from an old OS X backup?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, recovery

This is the format of the json backup (sensitive data replaced with 1s):

```
{"address":"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111","Crypto":{"cipher":"aes-128-ctr","ciphertext":"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111","cipherparams":{"iv":"11111111111111111111111111111111"},"kdf":"scrypt","kdfparams":{"dklen":32,"n":262144,"p":1,"r":8,"salt":"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"},"mac":"111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"},"id":"111111111111111111111111111","version":3}
```

Looks like it's version "3".

I've tried restoring this backup into Parity, MyEtherWallet.com, but they ask for a password.

I do not recall ever having to enter a password to secure my old wallet (that this backup is from).

Comment: There was never an optoin to create an unencrypted wallet file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your backup without the password is pretty much useless.

Your backup is your account information, but you still need your password for it.

You must definitely set up a password when you created this account.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you didn't store your password somewhere, your only option is to try to guess and then brute force recover your password.  [This article](https://cryptoassetrecovery.com/blog/recover-lost-blockchain-password/) will walk you through one approach to collecting enough information to make an educated password guess.

You can then use a tool like [pyethrecover](https://github.com/burjorjee/pyethrecover) to try to brute force your password.